# Difference between the Interest rate of bond and the interest rate of central bank

Tags: investing, trading, bonds, interest-rate, yield

Does the increase or decrease of the Interest rate (coupon rate) of bonds have the same effect as rising or falling interest rate of the central bank on the economy? In other words when we say that Interest rate is rising or falling then are we referring to the interest rate of the bond or the interest of the central bank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Interest rate" associated with a bond, or more precisely, yield, is not the same as the coupon rate. Coupon rate is the percentage of par/face value of the bond that is paid out periodically. The yield of a bond is the discount rate with which one discounts the cash flows associated with the bond taking into account the timings of the cash flows such that the sum of the discounted cash flows equals the price of the bond. The price and yield of a bond have an inverse relationship.

When they say interest rates are rising, it is the fed funds rate that they are referring to. It is the interest rate which banks charge each other to lend federal funds overnight. This rate influences the general level of interest rates in the market - basically the cost of borrowing money. The Fed raises this rate, for example, when they want to control inflation, by selling its securities to member banks reducing the available funds these banks have for lending to other banks so that they can raise their lending rates owing to money having become scarce. That makes borrowing expensive but controls inflation because people can't borrow easily and spend.

When the Fed wants to stimulate the economy it reduces this rate by buying securities from member banks increasing their available funds for lending forcing banks to reduce their lending rates. This reduces the general level of interest rates, and allows people to borrow more to invest or to spend and stimulates the economy.

Whenever the Fed buys bonds/securities their prices rise, and yields fall, and vice versa. So the Fed uses this buying and selling as a tool to control yields/interest rates.

Comment: So when someone says the bond has a 10% coupon rate then what does this mean? does this mean the bond pays 10% of the par value periodically? If so then how does this differs from the interest of 10%? why can't we say that the bond gives 10% interest?

Comment: does this mean the bond pays 10% of the par value periodically?  Yes, and it also pays the par/face value of the bond at maturity.  If so then how does this differs from the interest of 10%? When you say you get 10% interest from a bank it is on a certain principal that you lend out . In the case of a bond, there is no such fixed principal. Instead, in the arrangement that constitutes the bond the coupon values are fixed because they are a percentage of a fixed face value which is virtual in nature.

Comment: Once the coupon values have been determined they first decide what the bond should be worth and THEN solve for the interest rate/discount rate/yield that makes the sum of the discounted present values of the coupons and the final payment equal to the price.

Comment: So the yield of a bond is obtained indirectly, but a regular interest rate on a fixed deposit, for instance, is declared upfront and is applied to any given principal.

Comment: So coupons are like interest because they constitute periodic payments just like interest on a bank deposit, but the coupon rate is not exactly equivalent to the interest rate.

Comment: A simple example of a bond with 1 coupon paid out at 10% coupon rate and par value 100. At maturity, 10 (coupon) +100 (face value) will be paid out and someone is willing to pay 98 for this arrangement. So solve for i in 98 = 110/(1+i) to get i=12.24% which is the yield of the bond. Typically, when the bond makes only one payment it is just of the face value; this was just an artificial example meant to convey how coupon value and yield are calculated.

Comment: Understood. But It seems like the increase or decrease of the coupon rate has the same effect on the economy as the fed fund rate. for example, let's say the bond is at a 10% coupon rate and then new bond issued with a 12% coupon rate, this increase of coupon rate indicates that the cost of borrowing money has increased as well. Is that correct?

Comment: In your example, what if the buyer is charged more than proportionately more for the 12% coupon bond than for the 10% coupon bond? If this happens, the yield might fall for the 12% coupon bond. Continuing the above example, what if the buyer is ready to pay 101 for the 12% coupon? i will equal 10.89% which is less than 12.24% for the 10% coupon.

Comment: Interest rate is determined by how much you pay for borrowing. So you borrow some real amount today for which you have to pay another amount/amounts in the future. Both types of cash flows - the amount borrowed and the amount/s returned are real. But for coupon value calculation using the coupon rate only the coupon value is real - the par/face value is virtual. The corresponding real value for the coupon payments is the price of the bond and so interest rate/yield calculation must involve the price in addition to the coupon values. One pays the price and gets the stream of coupons in return.

Comment: It is immaterial to the calculation of yield how the coupon values are calculated. All you need to know for calculation of yield is how much you pay, and how much you get back and when.

Comment: Of course, the yield will fall for the 12% coupon bond and yield will keep falling as new bonds keep issuing with a higher coupon rate and if the coupon rate keeps increasing then at some point the cost of borrowing money will become so expensive. Isn't it?

Comment: No, that's not right. Why will the yield necessarily fall for the 12% coupon? What if the price of the bond is 99 for the 12% coupon? The yield is now 13.13%. The cost of borrowing money/yield is related to 1. how much you borrow 2. how much you pay back and when. Coupon rate is just a rate that is applied to a nominal value to calculate certain payments, and is specified upfront. It is not calculated by taking into consideration how much you pay versus how much you get back and when.

Comment: people will soon realize the 13.13% yield and start buying that bond hence rising bond price will lower the yield?

Comment: You wrote above "Of course, the yield will fall for the 12% coupon bond and yield will keep falling as new bonds keep issuing with a higher coupon rate " I said that this will not necessarily happen and I gave you an example. What you say might or might not happen. It depends on what people perceive to be a good yield.  The cost of borrowing/yield is determined by taking into consideration what you pay versus what you get and when you get it. Only coupon values do not determine yield or cost of borrowing. There is another component too viz. what you pay for the coupons.

Comment: If people decide not to buy bonds with higher coupon then money supply wouldn't grow, and if the market decides to keep buying bonds with higher coupon then at some point offering a higher coupon become too expensive for the issuer of the bond, hence the borrowing start to slow down.

Comment: You are just viewing at the coupons in isolation. That's not right. You should also look at what price is being paid for those coupons. What do you mean by "higher coupons becomes expensive for issuer"? What if the price paid for the coupons is also high?

Comment: I have added a reference to an answer. please check this out.

Comment: Yes. Read it. What exactly in that text are you referring to? If interest rates are expected to rise, that should reflect in the coupons AND the price of the bond. interest rate/yield = f(coupon value, price of bond). It could happen that the bond pays out a lower coupon rate than the interest rate but that its price is so low as to offset the effect of the low coupon rate and bring up the yield. So if interest rates are expected to go up, either the price of the bond will fall with the coupon rate remaining constant, or the coupon rates will rise with the price holding steady.

Comment: Yield rises with rising coupon rate provided price holds steady. If price also rises, yield might remain the same. There are 3 things here- coupon, yield, and price. They have to be considered together. Roughly speaking, coupon/(1+yield)=price.

Comment: So the rising yield indicating rising interest rate? And the yield is rising or not falling due to the rising coupon rate? as coupon rate rising or falling in tandem with the interest rate?

Comment: Yes, and yes if and only if price holds steady. Always bear coupon value/(1+yield)=price in mind. Two ways to increase yield - make the bond cheaper while maintaining the coupon rate, or increase the coupon rate while holding price steady.

Comment: How could yield rise if the price holds steady?

Comment: By increasing coupon rate.

Comment: Couldn't price fall as the coupon rate increase?

Comment: The thing is rising yield indicates a rising interest rate. Yield could rise if the bond price holds steady or fall. now the price can only hold steady or fall if the coupon rate rises because that will increase the yield. so yield rising because of the rising coupon rate as a result price hold steady or falling. Now at this point why can't I say that coupon rates have the same effect as interest rate cause coupon rate affects the yield and yield indicate interest rate?

Comment: "Couldn't price fall as the coupon rate increase?" Yes, only if the increase in yield more than offsets the increase in coupon rates. "Yield could rise if the bond price holds steady or fall." Depends on coupon rate.  Yield is a function of coupon rate and price.  Coupon rate does determine yield but only partially. There is price to consider too.

Comment: By considering the price can I say that coupon rates have the same effect as interest rate cause coupon rate affects the yield (considering the price) and yield indicate interest rate?

Comment: Only for a given price is the yield/interest rate determined by the coupon rate or vice-versa.  So if yield rises and the price is to be maintained, coupon rates must rise correspondingly.

Comment: Price could only fall if the coupon rate rises, practically there is no way the price could rise if the coupon rate rises. so the coupon rate determines the yield in this case. What am I missing?

Comment: Price could rise on a rise in coupon rates if yield stays steady or falls. When in doubt consider price = coupon/(1+yield).

Comment: But practically in the market that not gonna happen. yield will always rise if coupon rate rises so the price must fall.

Comment: in reality, yield can't stay steady or fall if the coupon rate increase so does the price can't rise if the yield is rising.

Comment: " yield will always rise if coupon rate rises so the price must fall. " Not necessarily. If coupon rates rise, price could rise to a level that makes yield fall.  "in reality, yield can't stay steady or fall if the coupon rate increase " Not necessarily. "so does the price can't rise if the yield is rising." I don't understand this.

Comment: So ultimately this is the yield that matters most to gauge the change in the interest rate and not necessarily the coupon rate or price. It is the yield that ultimately indicates the sentiment on the interest rate. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Yield is analogous to interest rate.

Comment: If you are fine with the answer, you might want to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Done, Thank you very much! The discussion was really helpful.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I think We both messed up! look the yield is just a function of coupon and price. so basically yield is optional in our calculation. it is not an essential element to prove our goal. so forget about the yield for a moment. in one comment you said, "Price could rise on a rise in coupon rates if yield stays steady or falls." the state of the yield is completely irrelevant in this case. The thing is no one in the right mind will ever pay more on an existing bond if the coupon rate rise. no need to mention the state of the yield either being flat or falling.

Comment: In a practical environment, i:e on the market, the price must fall if the coupon rate is rising, no matter what the yield is doing. because the yield is a derivative of the price and the coupon.

Comment: What do you mean by yield is "optional"? Do you mean it is not a free variable? What do you mean by " The thing is no one in the right mind will never pay more on an existing bond if the coupon rate rise. no need to mention the state of the yield either being flat or falling. "? If coupon rates rise, why would anybody not be willing to pay more if yield stay steady? Consider the equation price = coupon/(1+yield).

Comment: Strictly speaking, f(price, yield, coupon)= 0. There is an inter-relationship between price, yield, and coupon which is approximately price=coupon/(1+yield). If the values of two variables are chosen, the third variable's value is automatically determined. If coupon goes up but the yield remains the same, price must increase. If interest rates are fixed and somebody is ready to pay you more in coupons naturally they expect you to pay more for this arrangement.

Comment: I edited the comment a little bit. "What do you mean by yield is optional?" watch the video for this: https://youtu.be/I7FDx4DPapw

Comment: Which part of the video do you want me to watch?

Comment: After 6:45, https://youtu.be/I7FDx4DPapw?t=405

Comment: Watched. What's the point you want to make?

Comment: My real problem is that I am pretty much biased toward the thought that I see the coupon rate as the cost of borrowing money for the government and for the companies. I see the coupon rate as the interest rate for borrowing money.

Comment: Yes. That is evident from your arguments. It is the yield which is the analogue of interest rate - not coupon rate. Coupon rate is just applied to the par/nominal/face value of the bond to calculate the coupon payment which is fixed at the outset. You can use any coupon rate you want. Once it is fixed you price the bond taking into view what yield you want on it, and it is the yield which is reflective of the level of interest rates.

Comment: Don't compare coupon rate with the interest rate you get on a savings account. In a savings account what you lend to the bank is fixed, and you get interest in return which depends on the level of interest rates in the economy. So interest rate given by the bank = interest/principal. But for a bond what you pay for the bond is not fixed like the principal you lent out to the bank. Instead, what the bond pays you back is fixed, and you calculate what price you want to pay for that fixed payment so that you get the interest rate/yield you desire.

Comment: "It is the yield which is analogous of interest rate" Yes I can understand this. By the way, the point I was gonna make from that video is that many people when describing coupon rates are mixing it with the interest rates. as on that video, he describes that when the expectation of the interest rate rises the price fall. on the other hand, Anna Coulling writes in her book that when the expectation of the interest rate rises then the coupon rate rises too on the newer bonds. Because of that, I was thinking that the interest rate and the coupon rate reflect each other.

Comment: Yes. I can see why you have that bias. And it is easy to confuse between the two. They don't emphasize enough the difference between interest rate and coupon rate. That video was a simple example of how price and yield vary inversely given a fixed payment/coupon value. Coulling is right but she misses the potential for causing confusion. Coupon rates *tend* to rise on *new* bonds given prices are more or less stable but there is no mathematical reason why they *should necessarily* rise. They may remain the same and the price might fall to reflect the new higher yield.